# Assigning Child Pages to Non Existent Parent Pages in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'm surprised that after searching for so long I couldn't find any solution to my problem and so I thought of posting it here :)

So we can create 'pages' in WordPress and drag and drop them under 'menus' as we like to create a parent-child relationship. But what if we have a non-existent page using a custom link such as '#', how can we assign a child page to that particular parent page that doesn't exist?

So I have 'Parent 1' that has been added as a custom link under menus and the url is basically '#'. Obviously, that won't be registered as a parent page because it's a custom url but I don't need to add it as a parent page, it's more of a reference in the top menu. The main reason I'd want to do this is to make use of breadcrumbs. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Without messing with rewrite rules or custom slugs, why not just create a blank page and set the hierarchical relationship the normal way.

On the Menu you can still use the Custom Link `#` item and place the children accordingly. You can even name the blank page "Parent (Intentionally Left Blank)" so it's less confusing in the admin.

This would also allow you to have the appropriate hierarchical structure in your admin when you view the All Pages admin page that looks like:

- Parent (Blank)

  - Child 1
  - Child 2

Comment: There is wisdom in that and that is what I would have originally done but I kept thinking about the incredible amount of blank pages that would have to be created for say, a large website, and it takes up space on the page causing you to keep clicking on the 'next page' button. I was looking for some creative ways to tackle this challenge. I guess I have to decide between convenience and keeping my page list clean, lol. Thanks for your advise!

Comment: Well it would only take up 1 additional slot on the Next Page button if it overflows - you can combat this by changing the Screen Options in the upper right to display 21 pages instead of 20 (or even 40, whatever floats your boat). But yes you'll probably want a pros and cons list to determine what's best for your desired scale

Comment: Agreed. What are your thoughts about tackling the issue of clicking on the parent breadcrumb that we create as a blank page? When a user follows the trail and clicks on it it’ll just load a blank page right? Is there a way to force that blank # page to load the first menu item under the drop down menu?